# Unknown command in chromedriver

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, laravel-5, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I'm working on a PHP project and using dusk to conduct tests (OS: Ubuntu 20).
When I run the `chromedriver` on Linux and navigate to any URL, I am getting an unexpected error.
For example, the next error happens when I navigate to `localhost:9515/logo.png`:

```
{ "value":
    { "error":"unknown command",
      "message":"unknown command: unknown command: logo.png",
      "stacktrace":"#0 0x5561bf5e33e3 \u003Cunknown>\n#1 0x5561bf348468 \u003Cunknown>\n#2 0x5561bf3991de \u003Cunknown>\n#3 0x5561bf398f57 \u003Cunknown>\n#4 0x5561bf31f634 \u003Cunknown>\n#5 0x5561bf32044a \u003Cunknown>\n#6 0x5561bf60ff56 \u003Cunknown>\n#7 0x5561bf6272ad \u003Cunknown>\n#8 0x5561bf611dae \u003Cunknown>\n#9 0x5561bf627c34 \u003Cunknown>\n#10 0x5561bf605be2 \u003Cunknown>\n#11 0x5561bf31f206 \u003Cunknown>\n#12 0x7f5f2c10d0b3 \u003Cunknown>\n"}}
```

The problem is that dusk also navigates to webpages and instead of getting the HTML contents, it's getting the same error.

I'm completely stumped at two things.
First, why does there seem to be a recursion of unknown commands (it's as if the unknown command itself is the unknown command)?
Second, why is the unknown command pointing at the URL, or the file?

Things I have tried:

- I have already re-installed `chromedriver`
- I have confirmed that the version of the `chromedriver` is the same as the Chrome and Chromium versions (99)
- I have tried launching the `chromedriver` myself and using Laravel dusk, but the outcome remains the same

I would appreciate any help.

---

EDIT: Some more details.
**The below code works if I replace `http://127.0.0.1:9515` with `http://google.com/`**, for instance.

This is my `DuskTestCase.php` file, which I haven't really changed:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Laravel\Dusk\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

abstract class DuskTestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    /**
     * Prepare for Dusk test execution.
     *
     * @beforeClass
     * @return void
     */
    public static function prepare()
    {
        static::startChromeDriver();
    }

    /**
     * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
     *
     * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected function driver()
    {
        $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless'
        ]);

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            'http://127.0.0.1:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And this is the test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class ExampleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic browser test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/') // also experimented with localhost and 127.0.0.1 (with ports), but no change
                    // ->pause(2000)
                    ->assertSee('Sign In');
        });
    }
}
```

In the environment file, I have set `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:9515`.

Comment: When you navigate to this URL http://127.0.0.1:9515/logo.png from you browser, what do you get?

Comment: When I run `chromedriver` and navigate there, I get the same error as above. (logo.png doesn't really exist, I'm using it as an example, but the problem persists even with valid URLs, naturally.)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `localhost/logo.png` it should be something like `http://127.0.0.1:9515/logo.png`
I mean the command could be something like

```
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:9515/logo.png")
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I hadn't written the port (9515), but I am using it, and that is when the error appears. This is the code I'm using in Laravel: `$browser->visit('/')>assertSee('Sign In');`.

Comment: OK, I have updated the port in my answer accordingly

Comment: I am using the correct port. When I navigate to any URL with the port, I get the `"error": "unknown command"` with a message that doesn't quite tell me what the unknown command is (see my original post).

Comment: Again, I think instead of `localhost` it should be `http://127.0.0.1:` there

Comment: I tried that now: no luck. Both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` give me unexpected errors. It's like the driver seems to be interpreting the URLs as commands.

Comment: can you share the entire code line, not only the parameter passed to "where to navigate"?

Comment: Updated the original post. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: OK, I see. I'm not familiar with this syntax, I'm sorry... Using Java, previously some Python and C# but not PHP...

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying all the same :)